# Boundedness of an expression

Tags: expression-manipulation, core-language

First post on this part of the stackexchange network, I was just wondering if *Mathematica* allows one to quickly see if an expression is always within a certain range given values for the parameters it depends on?

For example, I have an expression $X = X(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ and know that two of those six variables are always positive and the other four are always negative.  I am finding it difficult to see in general whether this expression is within a certain range (e.g between $-1$ and $1$) by hand so was wondering whether this software would do it for me? It is part of a physics project and I have tried some numerical values by hand and the expression is indeed within the range required however seeing the general case is always more satisfactory.

Comment: You might want to look up `Reduce[]`. Without an expression for $X$, it's difficult to say something more helpful.

Comment: Many thanks, the expression for X is fairly complex as in it's not the most elegant of expressions but I could write it out if that would be beneficial? And thx, I'll look it up :)

Answer (score 4):

There's no single `BoundedQ` function that I know of, but there are several related functions:

[`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FunctionRange.html) tries to compute the range of a function:

```
range = FunctionRange[1/x, x, y]
(* y < 0 || y > 0 *)
```

It is clear that this is not bounded, but we can also try to get that result programmatically:

```
BoundedRegionQ@ImplicitRegion[range, y]
(* False *)
```

Or like this:

```
range /. {{y -> Infinity}, {y -> -Infinity}}
```

We see that both `Infinity` and `-Infinity` satisfy the inequalities, so the range is not bounded.

`FunctionRange` can also take conditions:

```
FunctionRange[{1/x, x > 1}, x, y]
(* 0 < y < 1 *)
```

With this condition it is bounded.

`FunctionRange` is meant to compute the exact range  I can imagine that in many situations it will be much easier to prove that a function is or isn't bounded than to compute the actual bounds.  In those cases this might be useful:

```
upperBoundGuess = 10

Resolve@Exists[x, 1/x > upperBoundGuess]
(* True *)

Resolve[Exists[x, Sin[x] > upperBoundGuess], Reals]
(* False *)
```

It tells us that `1/x` can get larger than `10` but `Sin[x]` cannot.  For the second case we needed to specify that we're working over the set of reals as `Sin[Pi/2 + 3 I]` is indeed real and greater than 10.

You can also use `Reduce` in place of `Resolve`.